# Error ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED running tests after updating Angular, Electron in NX workspace, how to fix it?

Tags: angular, electron, nrwl, nomachine-nx

I have an NX workspace where I use Angular, Electron and Nest. I recently tried to update my Angular and Electron separately because the nx migrate command wasn't working for me. However, after the update, I have not been able to run my tests since they are still in the NX environment.

Here is the NX version I'm using:

```
Nx Version:
- Local: v16.4.2
- Global: Not found
```

And my test configuration is set in the angular.json file as follows:

```
"test": {
  "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:karma",
  "options": {
    "main": "apps/frontend/src/test.ts",
    "polyfills": "apps/frontend/src/polyfills-test.ts",
    "tsConfig": "apps/frontend/src/tsconfig.spec.json",
    "karmaConfig": "apps/frontend/src/karma.conf.js",
    "scripts": [],
    "styles": ["apps/frontend/src/styles.scss"],
    "assets": ["apps/frontend/src/assets"],
    "customWebpackConfig": {
      "path": "./apps/frontend/angular.webpack.js",
      "target": "electron-renderer"
    }
  }
}
```

I try running the tests using the nx test frontend command, but it gives me the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'test').

When I tried using ng test, it gives me a different error ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED.

Here is the error log:
ng test
No tests found, exiting with code 0
...
01 07 2023 16:03:01.936:ERROR [karma-server]: Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
...

I suspect the issue might be related to Node.js version compatibility since the ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED error usually comes up when a function is used that is not supported by the current OpenSSL version embedded in Node.js.

Is there a way to resolve this issue and successfully run my tests? Any guidance would be appreciated.